# Oracle - PSQL compilation error

Tags: oracle

Can someone please tell me why this PSQL is coming up with a compilation error?

```
set serveroutput on
Create or replace function get_warehouse_location(Name in Customer.Name%type)
return w.location %type as
wLocation     warehouse.Location %type;
begin
select warehouse.location 
into wLocation
from Customer c, Warehouse w
where cName= 'Finch'
and warehouse.address='       ';
return (Location);
end;
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?  On first blush, you are returning `location` which is not a variable you have defined anywhere-- perhaps you mean to `return wLocation`.  Once you fix that, I would strongly expect that you'll get a runtime error because your `SELECT` returns too many rows.  You are doing a Cartesian join between the `customer` and `warehouse` tables so it is improbable that would return exactly 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least an issue with how you call the types.  Should be table.field%TYPE.  No spaces.

```
set serveroutput on
Create or replace function get_warehouse_location(Name in Customer.Name%type)
return w.location%type as
wLocation     warehouse.Location%type;
begin
select warehouse.location 
into wLocation
from Customer c, Warehouse w
where cName= 'Finch'
and warehouse.address='       ';
return (Location);
end;
```

Comment: It is legal (though admittedly uncommon) to have a space before the `%type`.